# Visual Studio Code - How can I remove the count in the top right corner?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

The number shows how many lines or characters I have changed and the white above it is a bar and after you finish the 8 would got 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 and then disappear.  When it does the text in my code flickers up and down. I removed a LOT of extensions but can't seem to find which one or what setting is doing this.

[image]

Comment: It is one of your extensions - powertools or something like that.

Comment: I assumed it was a extension but I have so many... will look for powertools

Answer (score 1):

Just found the Extension "Power Mode"  Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

I turned it off, paste these two lines in `setting.json`

```
powermode.combo.counterEnabled: hide,
powermode.combo.location: off
```